# Counting DISTINCT values in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to count the number of distinct email addresses in a view, but I can't figure out the syntax... Here's what I have:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserCount FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmailAddress 
    FROM viewCohortsAuthorizedByContractor
    WHERE (ListAccess = 1) AND (ContractorId = @id)
  )
END
```

The inner select works fine, but if I try adding the COUNT, I get the following error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure rptContractorUsersWithListUserCount, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 15]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

I'm sure there's a simple solution, I just can't figure it out...

Comment: You forgot to specify an alias for your subquery - `SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserCount FROM (...) as Q`. The keyword AS isn't necessary  - `SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserCount FROM (...) Q`. In your case SQLServer think that `END` is your alias. Early SteveB showed is more rightly query for your case.

Comment: Knew it was something simple. Just didn't think of an alias given that there weren't any clauses at the end (Where, Order By).

Comment: The syntax of TSQL requires that you specify an alias for a subquery in any case.

Comment: I said about subqueries which are located in the FROM-block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the subquery. Try this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT EmailAddress) as UserCount
FROM viewCohortsAuthorizedByContractor
WHERE (ListAccess = 1) AND (ContractorId = @id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserCount FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmailAddress 
    FROM viewCohortsAuthorizedByContractor
    WHERE (ListAccess = 1) AND (ContractorId = @id)
  )A   -----give a name for result set
END
```